# group by users usage on a shared folder in Red hat FS

Tags: bash, shell, unix

History: I have a shared folder which can be access by all the users of the system. every one claims that they are not using much. So, I decided to check how much each user uses the shared folder.

I am able to get the total usage by `du -sh <path/to/folder>`. but not at the individual users level.

I think, I am thinking too much to get this done. probably, there might be straight forward way to get this done.

If somebody asked similar kind of question please share the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of functions that may help

```
space() {
    local user=$1
    local space=0
    local tmp=`mktemp`
    find . -user $user -exec stat --printf="%s\n" {} \; 2>/dev/null >> $tmp
    for size in `cat $tmp`; do ((space=space + size)); done
    local humanized=`mb $space`
    echo "`pwd` $user $humanized"
    rm -f $tmp
}

mb() {
    local orig=$1
    if [[ $orig -gt $((2**20)) ]]; then
        echo -n $(($orig / 2**20))
        echo "mb"
    else 
        echo -n $(($orig / 2**10))
        echo "kb"
    fi
}
```

Paste these into your shell and then call it on the command line like

```
$space <user>
```

it will print out all the file sizes to a temporary file and then add them all up. The mb function makes it human readable. When I run it I get

```
/home/me me 377mb
```

Compared with

```
du -sh .
399M    .
```

Pretty close ;)